# Can I modify a global Liquid variable from inside a Jekyll include?

Tags: global-variables, jekyll, liquid

I would like to create to separate Jekyll includes that can both reference the same common variable. Here is a simplified scenario.

I create `_include/setter.html` with the following Liquid code:

```
{% globalString | append: include.add | append: "," %}
```

Then I create `_include/getter.html` with the following Liquid code:

```
we have {{ globalString }}
```

Then in my page I put:

```
{% include setter.html add = "one" %}
{% include setter.html add = "two" %}
{% include getter.html %}
```

I'd like to see a result something like `we have one,two,` as a result.

But of course `globalString` does not exist, so this cannot work. I can't seem to create new variables in `site` or `page` that can be seen from includes. For now I am awkwardly working around this with `capture`. Is there a better way to pass data *out* of an include in Jekyll?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be done setting the global variable before calling the *includes* and passing it as a parameter:

**_includes/setter.html**:

```
before: {{include.globalString}}<br>
{% assign globalString = include.globalString | append: include.add | append: "," %}
after: {{globalString}}<br>
```

**_includes/getter.html**: `we have {{ include.globalString }}`

Then:

```
{% assign globalString = "" %}
{% include setter.html add = "one" globalString=globalString%}
{% include setter.html add = "two" globalString=globalString%}
{% include getter.html globalString=globalString%}
```

Would output:

```
before:
after: one,
before: one,
after: one,two,
we have one,two,
```

## Update

It also works without passing the "global" variable as a parameter, the only requirement is to define it before calling the *includes*:

**_includes/setter.html**:

```
before: {{globalString}}<br>
{% assign globalString = globalString | append: include.add | append: "," %}
after: {{globalString}}<br>
```

**_includes/getter.html**: `we have {{ globalString }}`

```
{% assign globalString = "" %}
{% include setter.html add = "one" %}
{% include setter.html add = "two" %}
{% include getter.html %}
```

Comment: Wow, that is awesomely counter intuitive. The use of `globalString` in the setter, looks like a local variable. I had no idea that that would impact the value outside of the setter. Thanks! Super helpful!

Comment: @EFC Updated the answer, I've found out that also works without the parameter, code gets cleaner.